# WinEdt 10 no longer works with MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, winedt

I have been using WinEdt 10 on Windows 10 just fine. On a new install today, WinEdt 10 no longer works with MiKTeX, I'm assuming because of the new November package refactoring. Can someone help? I've followed the directions on MiKTeX's website, but literally LaTeX code that would compile on an older laptop last week (which I no longer have) will no longer compile on a new laptop with a fresh install of both WinEdt and MiKTeX. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tabularnewline
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\end{document}
```

The above used to compile, but now it does not. Any insight into what packages I may be missing? Note that if I comment out \providecommand, the code will compile.

Edit: You know what is odd, the following MWE does work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A \tabularnewline
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\end{document}
```

It seems I must have a character before the \tabularnewline \rule{}. With the old version of MiKTeX, this was not necessary. I'm not sure what's happening here.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What do you mean by it doesn't work? What error messages do you get?

Comment: The last error I see when I try to compile a previous file that would compile is:
    
    Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.
    ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
    
    See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
    Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
     ...                                              
                                                  
    l.12 \rule
          {\textwidth}{2pt}
    ? 

    Process has been terminated ...

Comment: Then you have errors in your latex code, that is not latexs fault. You probably have a ``\\`` where you should not.

Comment: No I don't. As I stated, the same LaTeX file compiled on my old laptop with: 1) the same version of WinEdt and 2) an older version of MiKTeX. Using a fresh install of WinEdt (same version though) and the new refactored MikTeX does not compile on the exact same LaTeX file. I believe it's an issue with the new refactored MiKTeX and WinEdt not working properly with the file paths.

Comment: Did you install with MPM the packages mentioned on MiKTeX website, which are not installed by MiKTeX Updater?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge- I've tried following the directions on MiKTeX website multiple times, and it looks like everything goes well, but then I can't get it to compile. I've finally found a MWE that I'll post above.

Comment: I'm using winedt 10 and I'm using miktex and it works  fine. So calm down, stop to speculate and show a minimal example that demonstrates your errors.

Comment: Please see above.

Comment: This never worked (I tried with miktex and texlive 2014, 2015, 2016)

Comment: When I comment out \providecommand, I get the following result (which I expected to get): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8177229/MWE.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your code never worked -- neither in older miktex or in TeXLive. It is an error to begin a paragraph with a new line.

If you didn't get errors on your old laptop with this code you probably compiled in `\nonstopmode` and so was able to ignore the errors. You could try to restore the old behaviour by adding in the menu `Options -> Execution modes -> pdflatex` in the field  "switches"`the option`--interaction=nonstopmode`.

But be warned: nonstopmode doesn't correct the errors it only avoids that the compilation stops. Ignoring errors is not a good idea in LaTeX. Even if it looks as if they are not serious, they indicate that something is wrong. You should always check the log file and correct them directly.